# "I'm being tested!"

Tags: discussion, support

When reviewing Suggested Edits, I often feel there should be another distinct reason to reject the edits:

**This is obviously a test!**

It's incredibly obvious when strings of nonsense words are ladled into an answer. We either need harder tests or another option that says "I know you're testing me. Can we get on with it?!"

Comment: Not really sure what is going on here. +1'd anyway

Comment: @Pokechu22 Nope, you have to choose a reason why you're rejecting it before it is revealed as an audit.

Comment: Apparently, clicking Reject in suggested edits does not immediately pass the audit. You have to choose a reason first. That's different from the VLQ review queue IIRC.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's supposed to be obvious.  Obviously bad edits in the review audits are there to trap robo-reviewers, not to stump serious reviewers paying close attention.  Just click `Reject`, click the "Ok, I passed" (or whatever it says) and move on your merry way.

Comment: You have to choose a rejection reason before you're notified of passing the audit. I normally use "Spam or Vandalism". The posts are normally so messed up by the fake edits that vandalism would seem like an appropriate characterization of the edit.

Comment: Indeed I didn't recall getting an audit in the edit queue to notice the difference. I went there now and my second review was an audit.  So really your question is _"why should there be a chosen reject reason at all?_" and I completely agree with you. In fact, that behavior _differs_ from the behavior of the Very Low Quality queue, which reports the audit success/failure right away before choosing a close reason.

Comment: @RetoKoradi There might already be other meta posts about this, as to why the suggested edit  audit requires choosing a reason.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. But as [Reto Koradi says](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280067/im-being-tested?noredirect=1#comment128991_280067), you have to give a reason. All the reasons seem improbable. Vandalism is the least-worst option. If SE is really testing just for robots, the message could just say that. "Well...you don't seem to be a robot. Good show! Carry on!"